# Default comment form in django not working

Tags: django, forms, comments

how does the `<form action={% commment_form_target %}` (the part in `{% .. %}`) work in django while using default comment framework? To which view will the action will be led to after post? Documentation says to "/comments/post". So do I have to create a comment app with a view post for the default comment framework to work?

Answer (score 0):

That template tag just is just returning reverse-resolved url for post_comment view.

Default view is bundled with the comments app: django.contrib.comments.view.post_comment.  You only need to make your own if you want to customize.  You would override get_form_target in your app to return reverse("customapp.post_comment") to use your own.